# Constraining all variances to be equal in multiple random intercepts linear models

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model

Let the mixed model formulation be the following:

```
outcome ~ fixed effects + (1|A) + (1|B) + (1|C)
```

A,B and C are binary covariates. Is there a way in R (either in nlme, lme4, etc) to estimate the variance of A, B and C to be the same? That is, instead of getting, say, the variance of the random intercept for A is 1.2, B is 1.5, and C is 1.8, the model would estimate the variance of A = B = C ~ 1.5.

Comment: It doesn't make a sense to fit random intercepts for a factor with only 2 levels. You would be asking the software to estimate a variance from only 2 observations. Imposing a further constraint that they should all be equal makes matters even worse.

Comment: In this case doesn't imposing the further restriction give you more observations to estimate the variance from?

Comment: Hmm. Why would that be the case ? Do you mean that by imposing the restriction then you are effectively saying that they are all from the same distribution, and therefore you have 6 observations ? Interesting. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way that you can impose a constraint on the variances. However, I can think of two ways you could achieve something similar:

- instead of fitting `(1|A) + (1|B) + (1|C)`, using `(1|A:B:C)`
- combine the three variables `A`, `B`, and `C` into a new variable, `D` which represents all the unique combinations of the three and fit `(1|D)`

Both approaches should be equivalent.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, or if not please let us know why so that it can be improved.